# Delete .. from .. join, same syntax for postgresql and oracle

Tags: postgresql, oracle, sql-delete

I need to execute the same exact query on oracle and postgresql, in which i need to delete rows from table 1, using a join on table 2.
I already had a working query, but it stopped working for oracle with 1000+ results in the "IN" statement.

```
delete from t1 
where
t1.oid IN 
(SELECT oid from t2 WHERE [condition])
```

I've read about joins but postgresql uses the "using" keyword instead

```
DELETE [target table]  
FROM   [table1]  
       INNER JOIN [table2]  
ON     [table1.[joining column] = [table2].[joining column]  
WHERE  [condition]
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Oracle does not support a JOIN or USING or something similar for the DELETE statement. Your only choices are `IN` or `EXISTS`, if you need something that works on Postgres and Oracle.

If an `IN` condition is too slow then try an EXISTS condition:

```
delete from t1 
where exists (select * 
              from t2
              where t2.oid = t1.oid
                and [condition])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use and multi-dimensional `IN` expression (which should work up to 100,000 items):

```sql
DELETE FROM t1 
WHERE ( t1.oid, 1 ) IN ( SELECT oid, 1 FROM t2 );
```

or `EXISTS` (which should work for any volume of rows):

```
DELETE FROM t1 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t1.oid = t2.oid );
```

And add the `WHERE` condition into the sub-query as required.

[PostgreSQL db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bff7f5c70ade512ae6792a69350211e5)

[Oracle db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a1f47df5b153f7f3e3f9bf0091e93cd9)

Comment: Thanks, both methods work as intended! I've compared the select times of both solutions and on a 1200 rows dataset it seems the "in" method is slightly faster than the "exist" method